# Symmetry and Alignment

Tags: mesh, selection-tools, properties, scale, axis

I'm creating a snowman while watching a tutorial
so I got these 2 eyeballs on him
how do I make sure that they are on symetrical spots on the huge snowball of the head, and how do I make sure that all three body parts (big snow balls) are aligned properly, (none of them has to be a lil left or a lil right, or a lil more up, or a lil more down), you get what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can always position things by typing in there exact coordinates [numeric input](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/precision/numeric_input.html). Also [snapping](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html) to an axis or the grid can help you align things. For symetry the [mirror modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/mirror.html) is often the goto thing.

[More precision tools](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/precision/index.html)

Comment: I literary did not understand a thing on that numeric input page, I'm a total newbie, there's too much useless info for me (useless because I stick to basic lessons first). For the snapping thing I'm not sure how that exactly helps with symetry and alignment? And while mirror modifier would probably help, there's a bunch of info on the site that I just get lost reading it. I don't understand... Man, every year I come back to this program full of willpower and always loose the passion quickly because I'm bombarded by professional terminology and information :(

Comment: I guess getting into the brode topic of CG is a hard thing... for me it worked following tutorials step by step ... mostly without understanding wat i was dooing... and later on pice by pice it came together. And it mattert less and less which button i exactly had to press but more about understanding the process behind it. Dont be so hard with yourself. Throw stuff away if you are stuck and dont let it frustrate you to mutch ... youst make shour start with a new small thing new the next day :) and eventually you will have folders and folders of wierd and funny things to loock back on ;)

Comment: Where are you getting stuck on using the mirror modifier? Understand that the mirroring operation will use the pivot center of your object to define the plane for mirroring, unless you have specified it to be something else, such as the 3D cursor. Practice creating a UV sphere in an empty scene. Do not move it once created, and instead, go into Edit Mode, cut it exactly in half and delete either half. Go into Object Mode and put a mirror modifier on the remaining half and see if you can make it back into a sphere again. Let us know if it works, and if not, let us know what went wrong and when.